# Does Minecraft require any further online connectivity after initial login?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After initial account creation and first log in - does Minecraft ever require further logging in or can it be then just played offline / with offline servers without WAN connectivity? I'm concerned about some timeouts of login so lets say if I don't launch game for 2 years, do I need to log in again? (lets say I don't want to update if it matters)

I'm talking about legit copy of Minecraft Java edition.

Comment: i can only speak for offline single player and i haven't updated Minecraft since 1.8 (thus this could ve very outdated) but you still need online connectivity to download the version of minecraft you have set for that profile. ie. if you get the latest version and then later you want to play 1.7.10 then you need to go online for it to download the 1.7.10. after it's been downloaded you should be able to freely switch between the 2 without the internet. this is what Forge does for 1.7.10 by creating a separate modded version

Comment: @Memor-X If there is no internet connection, the launcher doesn't know about the update, so it doesn't try to download it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only things that definitely require an internet connection are:

- Playing on a server
- Updating Java, the launcher or the game automatically
- Getting out of demo mode when playing for the first time

Note: I sometimes have issues where the login or that fact that the Minecraft version is already downloaded gets forgotten, but I don't know what causes it, I have pretty complicated setups. Usually it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Java can be updated offline. It's because lots of enterprise servers relay on java and datacenter policies deny outgoing connections from servers for security reasons, so all patches are applied offline via offline delta packages. Java is pretty enterprise tech. I certainly doubt Mojang would do such thing for Minecraft client tho... That's pretty much why I'm asking because I'm using airgapped (network isolated) Linux workstation and I happen to also use it for games sometimes no matter how comically it sounds... So I hope I could just activate it on different machine then copy to workstation

Comment: Yes, that way it's also possible to update the launcher by moving a new installer to it. And for getting out of demo mode, you can try logging in on another device and moving all game data (`.minecraft` folder) to the offline device.